# Generalized metric on spacetimes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I read many articles about space-times. Most authors consider these spaces as warped product manifolds $I\times M$ where $I$ is an open connected interval of the real line and $M$ is a Riemannian manifold. Minkowski space-time, anti-de Sitter, and the Einstein static universe are well-known examples of such space-times. Many authors considered a general metric of these three examples and construct the so-called static space -times.

***My question is:*** Is there a generalized metric on all space-times?

**Note** that my question is not about the most generalized metric but about the generalized metric of the existing ones.

**I want to bank up the existing metrics in one generalized metric.** One may consider for example $I\times S^n$.
  Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you asking: "Are all Ricci flat Lorentzian manifolds of the form $-f^2 dt^2 + g$ where $g$ is a Riemannian metric"? In this case, the answer is no, e.g. Kerr is not "static"

Comment: @OtisChodosh a simple version of my question is "can we merge or combine all existing metrics on space-times in one generalized metric such that the existing ones become special cases"

Comment: Sorry but I still do not understand. For example, what do you mean by "bank up"?